# Activemq topic subscribers doubles the messages

Tags: weblogic, spring-jms

I have an application in weblogic clustered environment. There are 2 servers in this cluster. I want to use durable subscription so for each server I needed to give different clientId. ClientIds should be unique for server. But when I receive message It doubles this way. I want to make group of these clients and use as queue. This way if one of the server get the message then the other will not get any message. How can I achieve this? Using queue is forbidden. I need to use topic.

Edit: I use Weblogic as application server. My application is basic Spring JMS listener.

Comment: The question is tagged with activemq-artemis, but it also indicates you're using Weblogic. Please clarify what broker you're using as well as what client API and protocol. Thanks!

Comment: How can you have a "basic spring activemq listener" connecting to Weblogic? That doesn't really make any sense. I think you mean "basic Spring JMS listener," right?

Comment: Yes basic JMS listener. I am listenening activemq topics.